# Google Maps Javascript not getting Coordinates of user

Tags: javascript, maps

This javascript wont get the coordinates of the user 
(this is a html, js and css application only)
(the area with Bold and Italic text, is the one supposed to get the coordinates from the client)

I have tried different soloutions, and they wont work, + it doesnt show the ones if the user is within 25km

center: new google.maps.LatLng(***val(coords.latitude***),***val(coords.longitude)***),

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  var side_bar_html = ""; 

  var gmarkers = []; 

  var map = null;
  var markerclusterer = null;

function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,

    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

 gmarkers.push(marker);

 side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
}


function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(val(coords.latitude),val(coords.longitude)),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', find_closest_marker);


  downloadUrl("markers.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
    var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
      var sted = markers[i].getAttribute("sted");
      var html="<b>"+sted+"</b><br>"+id;

      var marker = createMarker(point,sted+" "+id,html);
    }
    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);

    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
          });
        }

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
      { 
        size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
      });


    function find_closest_marker( event ) {
        var closestMarker = -1;
        var closestDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        for( i=0;i<gmarkers.length; i++ ) {
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(gmarkers[i].getPosition(),event.latLng);
            if ( distance < closestDistance ) {
                closestMarker = i;
                closestDistance = distance;
            }
        }
        map.setCenter(gmarkers[closestMarker].getPosition());
        if (map.getZoom() < 16) map.setZoom(16);
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[closestMarker], 'click');
    }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user a simple JS function for that.

```
 <script>


function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLatLng);
    } else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showLatLng(location) {
    alert("Latitude: " + location.coords.latitude + 
    "Longitude: " + location.coords.longitude); 
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Where am i supposet to implement it inside the script so that the coordinates is correct? as i showed with Bold and italic text